# Check last row from phpmyadmin database with PHP

Tags: php, pdo

I am building a website and I want to add "previous" & "next" buttons to send the user to the previous or the next page. So i tried this:

```
<a href="?p=posts&pid='.($_REQUEST['pid']-1).'" class="next_page fa fa-hand-o-left" title="Previous page"></a>
```

where 'pid' is the 'post id' I did the same thing for 'next page' button

```
<a href="?p=posts&pid='.($_REQUEST['pid']+1).'" class="next_page fa fa-hand-o-right" title="Next page"></a>
```

it worked... but it continues even if the page with that ID doesnt exist. im wondering if I could get some help with 'checking if current page is first row or last row.'.

Here's my code:

```
<?php
    require('connect.php');
    if(preg_match('/[^0-9]/i', $_REQUEST['pid'])) {
       echo '<div style="margin:50px auto;" class="warning_msg">WARNING: !! Illegal character detected !! >> <b>'.$_REQUEST['pid'].'</b></div>';
    } else {
        $post_ = $dbh->query('SELECT * FROM `posts` WHERE `id`='.$dbh->quote($_REQUEST['pid']).'')->fetch();

        echo '<div class="_header_ p_header_ disable_padding">
              <a href="?p=posts&pid='.($_REQUEST['pid']-1).'" class="prev_page fa fa-hand-o-left" title="Previous Post"></a>
     '.$post_['title'].'
              <a href="?p=posts&pid='.($_REQUEST['pid']+1).'" class="next_page fa fa-hand-o-right" title="Next Post" ></a>
              </div>
              <div>'.$post_['article'].'</div>
              <div class="_footer_">posted by <a href="/profile.php?uid='.$post_['user_id'].'"><i>'.$post_['author'].'</i></a> on &raquo; '.date('M d Y H:m:i', strtotime($post_['post_time'])).'</div>';
    }
?>
```

EDIT (SOLVED):
to find the first & last row i used a single query

```
$page = $dbh->query('SELECT MIN(id), MAX(id) FROM `posts`')->fetch();
```

and used like :

```
/* if current post id is equals to last id from posts */
if($_REQUEST['pid'] == $page[1]) { $next_page = $_REQUEST['pid'].'#';}
else { $next_page = ($_REQUEST['pid']+1); }

/* if current post id is equals to first id from posts */
if($_REQUEST['pid'] == $page[0]) { $prev_page = $_REQUEST['pid'].'#';}
else { $prev_page = ($_REQUEST['pid']-1); }
```

```
<a href="?p=posts&pid='.$prev_page.'" class="prev_page fa fa-hand-o-left" title="Previous Post"></a>
<a href="?p=posts&pid='.$next_page.'" class="next_page fa fa-hand-o-right" title="Next Post"></a>
```

Comment: phpMyAdmin is not a database its a tool written in PHP that helps you administer a MYSQL database

Comment: I know we are not suppose to point people at tutorials, but you should check how it should be done. You are missing a few simple basic concepts that make it quite easy http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-paginate-data-with-php--net-2928 and making an answer would take far to long

Comment: `SELECT fields FROM table ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1;`

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$lastpage = 10;
$ppage = isset($_REQUEST['pid']) && $_REQUEST['pid'] > 1 ? ($_REQUEST['pid']-1) : 0; 
$npage = isset($_REQUEST['pid']) && $_REQUEST['pid'] < $lastpage ? ($_REQUEST['pid']+1) : $lastpage; 
?>
<a href="?p=posts&pid=<?=$ppage?>" class="next_page fa fa-hand-o-left" title="Previous page"></a>
<a href="?p=posts&pid=<?=$npage?>" class="next_page fa fa-hand-o-right" title="Next page"></a>
```

Here i put a constant value 10 for last page.Instead of that you have to find outlast page id and replace that.Php pagination scripts are also available to find out first and last pages..

Comment: Your code seems good, but my question is 'how can I check if current 'pid' is the last in database

Comment: // QUERY TO GET NEXT POST ID
SELECT * FROM posts WHERE id = (SELECT min(id) FROM posts WHERE id > '.$dbh->quote($_REQUEST['pid']).')
// QUERY TO GET PREVIOUS POST ID
SELECT * FROM posts WHERE id = (SELECT max(id) FROM posts WHERE id < '.$dbh->quote($_REQUEST['pid']).')

Comment: add these queries result instead of $ppage and $npage

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But a friend of mine helped me with the problem. I've UPDATED my question and posted the solution.